# mIRC: Check if INI-file has a key

Tags: scripting, mirc

I'm trying to see if there is a entry in a ini-file with a user's nick as the key or not. If not; make an entry. If it exists; post a error message.

```
var %previous = $readini(numbers.ini,Number,$nick)

if(%previous != $null) {
  msg $chan $nick , you have already written %previous .
}
else {
  writeini numbers.ini Number $nick $2
  msg $chan $nick has written $2.
}
```

What's happening with the script above is that it is never `$null`, and I can't find anywhere what is returned from `$readini` if a key is not found.

Comment: I've tested it seems that there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

`$ini(numbers.ini, Numbers, $nick)` will return number N (indicating that the item is the Nth item in that section) if it exists. If it does not exist, it will return `$null`.

In your case, you'll want something along the lines of

```
if ($ini(numbers.ini, Numbers, $nick) != $null) {
  msg $chan $nick , you have already written $readini(numbers.ini, Numbers, $nick)
}
else {
  writeini numbers.ini Numbers $nick $2
  msg $chan $nick has written $2.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `$ini`-suggestion, but the if still fails. With the code you posted I always get `User has written 30.`

Comment: Phil, I accidentally included typo's. It wrote to the section `Number` instead of `Numbers`, so it would never detect the new value. Also, the `$readini` read from `$numbers.ini` instead of `numbers.ini`. Both are now fixed. I guess that's what I get for not testing code! Let me know if this works.